# What is it called - get most common word(s) segments from list of keywords?

Tags: c#, .net

Lets say I have a list of keywords

```
free numerology compatibility
numerology calculator free
free numerology report
numerology reading
free numerology reading
etc...
```

By what c# algorithm or what is it called so I can further research it, when I want to get the following results?

```
6 instances of "numerology"
3 instances of "free numerology"
2 instances of "numerology reading"
1 instance of "numerology compatibility"
1 instance of "numerology calculator"
etc...
```

Comment: Search for * word frequency analysis
* or just frequency analysis

Comment: Take a look at the [Aho–Corasick string matching algorithm][1] Wikipedia entry. There is also a [CodeProject ][2] implementation in C#. [1]:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm
[2]:http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12383/Aho-Corasick-string-matching-in-C

Comment: I would call it phrases not keywords as you are looking for order also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subject you are looking goes by the name of **Term Frequency Analysis** or **Word Frequency Analysis**.The following code can give you the frequency of each word. It is also very easy to find the frequency of a given phrase BUT doing analysis on the whole document and finding sequence of terms that have frequency above 1 is a bit more complicated.

```
void Analyze(ref String InputText, ref Dictionary<string, int> WordFreq)
{
    string []Words = InputText.Split(' ');

    for (int i = 0; i < Words.Length; i++)
    {
        if (WordFreq.ContainsKey(Words[i]) == false)
            WordFreq.Add(Words[i], 1);
        else
        {
             WordFreq[Words[i]]++;
        }
    }
}

void DoWork()
{
    string InputText = "free numerology compatibility numerology calculator free free numerology report numerology reading free numerology reading";
    Dictionary<string, int> WordFreq = new Dictionary<string,int>();

    Analyze(ref InputText,ref WordFreq);

    string result = null;
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> pair in WordFreq)
    {
        result += pair.Value + " Instances of " + pair.Key + "\r\n";
    }

    MessageBox.Show(result);
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DoWork();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through an array of words and store the count using a dictionary.

e.g.

```
Dictionary d = new Dictionary<string, int>();

foreach (string word in wordList)
{
    if (d.ContainsKey(word))
    {
       d[word]++;
    }
    else
    {
       d[word] = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: He's not just looking for words though, he's looking for phrases.  That complicates matters.